# detecting the coordinates where a bullet hits a mesh

Tags: opengl, c++

I have a lot of complex objects in a scene and im looking for an efficient way to find which object a fired bullet hits and to find the hit coordinates.
It would be best if there was a lightweight library to do this.
it seems that PhysX can do this, but i didnt find a way except to give every face in every mesh a physX system and that seems to become a bottleneck.

thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [detecting the coordinates where a bullet hits a mesh](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12524/detecting-the-coordinates-where-a-bullet-hits-a-mesh)